# How to account for Postgresql rank() ties

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table `teams` with 30 rows and has a handful of statistics stored as attributes. For example, goals for, goals against, etc and I've created a view that uses rank() and does a good job ranking the records. Here's an abridged query example and resulting table:

```
SELECT name,
   points, 
   rank() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS point_tank
FROM teams;


         name          | points    | point_rank
-----------------------+-----------+----------------
 Team 1                |        14 |              1
 Team 2                |        11 |              2
 Team 3                |         9 |              3
 Team 4                |         9 |              3
```

I would like to add an additional column that would return boolean based on whether or not the rank is a tie. eg Team 3 and Team 4 in this example. It might look something like this:

```
         name          | points    | point_rank     | tie
-----------------------+-----------+----------------+----------------
 Team 1                |        14 |              1 |          false
 Team 2                |        11 |              2 |          false
 Team 3                |         9 |              3 |           true
 Team 4                |         9 |              3 |           true
```

Any ideas here? Or am I approaching this incorrectly and abusing rank() here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a CTE and then use the lag/lead functions to check for ties:

```
with ranked as (
  SELECT name,
        points, 
        rank() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS point_rank
  FROM teams
)
select name, points, point_rank, 
       (   point_rank = lag(point_rank, 1, -1::bigint) over (order by point_rank) 
        or point_rank = lead(point_rank, 1, -1::bigint) over (order by point_rank)
       ) as is_tie
from ranked;
```

The default value for the lag and lead function is needed for the first and last row, to avoid checking for null there.

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/-01aFLr4

Comment: Thanks, this worked and it helped me understand CTEs better.

Comment: The example link is Patreon only, so here's another option to play with it: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/b11b28f

Comment: Nice edit to dbfiddle, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to place your current query into a common table expression and then use it to identify which ranks are duplicate:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT name,
           points, 
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS point_rank
    FROM teams;
)

SELECT cte.name,
       cte.points,
       cte.point_rank
       CASE WHEN t.point_rank IS NOT NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS tie
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT point_rank
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY point_rank
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) t
    ON cte.point_rank = t.point_rank
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
   , points
   , rank() OVER (rrr) AS point_rank
   -- , count(*) OVER (ppp) AS ppp_cnt
   , rank() OVER (pp2) AS sub_rank
   , (COUNT(*) OVER (ppp) > 1) AS is_tie
FROM teams
WINDOW ppp AS (PARTITION BY points )
        , pp2 AS (PARTITION BY points ORDER BY ctid )
        , rrr AS (ORDER BY points DESC)
ORDER BY points DESC
        ;
```

---

Result (I added two extra rows):

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
  name  | points | point_rank | sub_rank | is_tie 
--------+--------+------------+----------+--------
 Team_1 |     14 |          1 |        1 | f
 Team_2 |     11 |          2 |        1 | f
 Team_3 |      9 |          3 |        1 | t
 Team_4 |      9 |          3 |        2 | t
 Team_5 |      5 |          5 |        1 | t
 Team_6 |      5 |          5 |        2 | t
(6 rows)
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY ctid` seems fishy as the ctid will change when the row is updated (and HOT updates can not be used)

Comment: Yes, it is fishy, but it is not supposed to be stable, it is only used to disambiguate the ties into the "sub_rank". But you could use the team name or -number, or the subscription date instead.